# My custom validator in AdonisJs is not working

Tags: customvalidator, adonis.js

I followed the Adonis documentation about how to make a custom validator. I made it so simple just for testing.

When I made the "post", I receive the message **"cpf is not defined as a validation rule"**.

The codes:

**Cpf.js**

```
const Validator = use('Validator')

const cpfValidation = async (data, field, message, args, get) => {
  const value = get(data, field)

  console.log('This line is on console!')

  if (!row) {
    throw message
  }
}

Validator.extend('cpf', cpfValidation)
```

**User.js**

```
'use strict'

class User {

  get validateAll() {
    return true
  }

  get rules() {
    return {
      name: 'required',
      lastname: 'required',
      email: 'required|email|unique:users',
      cpf: 'cpf',
      birthday: 'required',
      password: 'required|min:6|max:20'
    }
  }
}

module.exports = User
```

The result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dwIN.png

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After breaking my head a little, I found the solution.

First of, I have to install the adonis provider validation:
**adonis install @adonisjs/validator**

And put it in the list of providers inside the **start/app.js**:

```
const providers = [
  '@adonisjs/validator/providers/ValidatorProvider'
]
```

Then I create a new provider by:
**adonis make:provider CustomProvider**

It gonna create a new provider on the folder **"providers" in root.**

My code for this class is:

```
'use strict'

const { ServiceProvider } = require('@adonisjs/fold')

class CustomValidator extends ServiceProvider {

  async isCpfCorrect(data, field, message, args, get) {
    const cpf = get(data, field);

    //It will be validated by "unique" validation, if value is null
    if(!cpf){
       return
    }

    /*
      ALL MY LOGIC SHOULD BE HERE...
    */

  }

  register() { }

  boot() {
    const Validator = use('Validator');
    Validator.extend('cpf', this.isCpfCorrect);
  }
}

module.exports = CustomValidator
```

Then I have to add this provider in the list of providers of **start/app.js**:

```
const path = require('path')

const providers = [
  '@adonisjs/framework/providers/AppProvider',
  '@adonisjs/auth/providers/AuthProvider',
  '@adonisjs/bodyparser/providers/BodyParserProvider',
  '@adonisjs/cors/providers/CorsProvider',
  '@adonisjs/lucid/providers/LucidProvider',
  '@adonisjs/mail/providers/MailProvider',
  '@adonisjs/framework/providers/ViewProvider',
  '@adonisjs/validator/providers/ValidatorProvider',
  path.join(__dirname, '..', 'providers', 'CustomValidator')
]
```

Then I will be able to use my provider in validation:

```
'use strict'

class User {

  get validateAll() {
    return true
  }

  get rules() {
    return {
      name: 'required',
      lastname: 'required',
      email: 'required|email|unique:users',
      cpf: 'required|cpf' <--------------- here is my custom provider for cpf,
      birthday: 'required',
      password: 'required|min:6|max:20'
    }
  }
}

module.exports = User
```

All of these I found in the doc:

https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/service-providers
and
https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/extending-adonisjs

Cheers.